# search string wildcard and display to textbox and combo boxes data

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, combobox, textbox

i have a code here for a search string and display data to the textbox and combo boxes but have a minor error any one can help me to revise the code

```
Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
    "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true"

    sqlconn.open()

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tblOfficeEquipmentProfile where OE_ID like '%" & txtSearchOEID.Text & "%'", sqlconn)
    da.Fill(dt)
```

this line is underligned by blue and display error "OVERLOAD RESOLUTION"

```
New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tblOfficeEquipmentProfile where OE_ID like '%" & txtSearchOEID.Text & "%'", sqlconn)
```

as i am concerned this is to display data on a datagrid.. but this time i want to display data on textboxes and combo boxes

Comment: still the same error sir

Comment: overload resolution  failed because no accessible New can be called with this arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a SqlConnection as a 2nd parameter to a OldDbDataAdapter creation.

```
Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
....
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
....
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select .....%'", sqlconn)
```

You should NOT be mixing OleDb with SQL .Net objects...
Either use a
**SqlDataAdapter** with **SqlConnection** or an
**OleDbDataAdapter** with **OleDbConnection**.

Comment: sir it worked i replaced the sql conn

dim conn as oledbconnection

my new problem now is the da.fill(dt)

since this code is for datagrid..can you help me revise the code to display data on textboxes and combo boxes instead of datagrid